# Como enviar emails automaticamente para usuários após se cadastrarem em meu site?

Tags: php, javascript

A dúvida é a seguinte:
Eu queira que o usuário após se cadastrar no site, recebesse um email.
Eu queria saber como fazer de duas formas..

1°: "Recebesse um link para ativar a conta."
2°: "Recebesse apenas uma mensagem, informando que foi cadastrado, e etc.."

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Fico muito grato desde já, e espero respostas.

Comment: Já testaste algua coisa? Tens alguma base de dados ou estrutura de armanezamento de dados?

Comment: Sergio, não. Não tenho nada pronto, só quero saber como funciona, ou como fazer..

Comment: A pergunta é meio ampla mas posso te dar um caminho.. Para enviar e-mails você usa a função `mail()` você pode ler sobre ela no php.net ou pesquisando. Para você ficar enviando e-mails você primeiramente vai ter que ter um banco de dados contendo os e-mails desses usuários, uma página administrativa para você escrever o conteúdo e enviar os e-mails em massa.. Desculpe não orientar todos os pontos, é ampla como eu disse, pois envolve várias coisas..

Comment: Obrigado Elaine, vou dar uma pesquisada, agradeço desde já! Abraços.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo irei tentar te ajudar. BOm segue as etapas :
1) na sua funcao de registrar o user (crie um status(ativo/inativo) use a funcao gere um codigo que pode ser o nome dele ou data hora com md5 (`md5(var_data)`)
2) registre esse código em uma tabela vinculado ao id do user
3) crie uma pagina responsável por receber o codigo e verificar de qual user é e alterar o status.
4) apos registrar o codigo e o cadastro do user use a funcao `mail()` para enviar o link da pagina de verificacao com no final um atributo $_GET
Acredito que de certo

Comment: Haha, obrigado Augusto!! Irei tentar, valeu.

Comment: De nada .... Se der erro pode falar